# nginx proxy_pass and docker - I don't want port number in address bar

Tags: wordpress, nginx, docker, proxypass

On mywebsite.com, I have running docker container with wordpress.
I started it as

```
docker run -p 8000:80 --name docker-wordpress-nginx -d
```

and

```
docker ps
```

shows

```
0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp
```

and on my host I have nginx running with

```
server {
     listen   80;
...
server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
...
location / {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

when i go here

```
mywebsite.com
```

It brings wordpress index page of my site, but address in browser is now

```
mywebsite.com:8000
```

instead of

```
mywebsite.com
```

which I expected.
Everything looks as i wanted except that I always get that port number in address

```
http://mywebsite.com:8000/2015/08/01/hello-world/
```

Instead, I wanted

```
http://mywebsite.com/2015/08/01/hello-world/
```

i mean, in general, instead of

```
http://mywebsite.com:8000/some_blog/
```

i want

```
http://mywebsite.com/some_blog/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you'd get better help for this on the ServerFault site as it's about nginx config (hence vote to close). I've tried to answer, but I'm not sure if I'm correct.

Comment: I note this question has now been answered on server fault https://serverfault.com/questions/710153/nginx-proxy-pass-and-docker-i-dont-want-port-number-in-address-bar. Can we close it or answer it here?

Comment: Yes, we can. Thank you.